# Use input as array, then multiply by value of index and get sum

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, dom

Sorry if I get my terms wrong I am new to this!

What I am trying to do is get the user to input 4 digits, put those into an array, and then multiply those numbers by itself, then return the sum.   Example:

User inputs 1234
What I want it to do:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
The math I want: (1*1) + (2*2) + (3*3) + (4*4)
output: 30

This is what I have done:

```
arr = [];
var number= parseInt(document.getElementById("number"));
arr.push(number);
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
 sum += (arr[i]*arr[i]) ;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Where am I going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: You're not splitting the input into separate digits.

Comment: Please check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an array with one element, the entire number that the user entered.

You need to split the input into separate numbers for each digit.

Also, you have to use the `.value` property to get what the user entered.

```
arr = [];
var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(number[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the legible `for`-`of` syntax -

```js
const numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

let result = 0

for (const num of numbers)
  result = result + (num * num)

console.log(result) // 30
```

You could also use `Array.prototype.reduce` -

```js
const numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

const result = numbers.reduce((result, num) => result + (num * num), 0)

console.log(result) // 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I've provided full example with comments. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
const doMagic=(numberInput)=>{
  // if it doesn't have value, return false
  if (!numberInput && numberInput.value) return false;
  // split input value by each character
  const arr = numberInput.value.split('');
  let sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    sum += (arr[i]*arr[i]);
  return sum;
}

// get element, not value
const numberInput = document.getElementById("number");
// on elements value change call our function
numberInput.addEventListener('change',()=>
  console.log(doMagic(numberInput))
);
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this to teach you `loop`, not `array` and `slice`, You can do this using simple `while loop` and `mathematics`.

```js
// var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("number"));

var number = 1234;
let sum = 0;
for (; number > 0; ) {
  const x = Math.floor(number % 10);
  sum += x * x;
  number = Math.floor(number / 10);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
arr = [];
var number= document.getElementById("number");
arr = number.split("");// Splits the input into a string array like ["1","2","3","4"]
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
 sum += (arr[i]*arr[i]) ;
}
console.log(sum);
```

Note: JS is very loose when it is trying to check for type of input.
Input is assumed to be always of integer format.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const input = document.getElementById("number");
const arr = [...input.toString()];
const sum = arr.reduce((total, item) => {
  const num = parseInt(item);
  const multipy = num * num;
  return (total += multipy);
}, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer (please click on Run code Snippet)

```js
function getTotal() {
  arr = [];
  // you forget to put .value here
  var numbersAsAString = document.getElementById('number').value;
  // => 1234

  // and you need to take each digit from the input you insert
  for (var i = 0; i < numbersAsAString.length; i++) {
    // and as you did parseInt to convert string to number
    arr.push(parseInt(numbersAsAString[i]));
  }
  // console.log(arr); // [1,2,3,4]
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i] * arr[i];
  }
  // console.log(sum);
  document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML="Answer will be here: "+sum;
}

// If you need any explanation, or this is not what you are asking about, please comment on my answer
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>StackOverFlow &#127831;</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/2057/2057586.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Stack Over Flow &#127831;</h3>

  <input id="number" type="text" value="1234">

  <button onclick="getTotal()">get the answer</button>
  <p id="answer">Answer will be here: </p>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need any explanation, or this is not what you are asking about, please comment on my answer